# OpenPBS build error - Unknown type name 'jid_t'

Tags: c, ubuntu, pbs

I already installed OpenPBS previously. I wanted try to configure with different command this time and install it.

command :

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/pbs --enable-alps
```

and I get this error :
[image: PBS Error]

I followed [this article](https://medium.com/@anarmammadli/how-to-install-openpbs-20-0-1-on-ubuntu-b1cc62cfb0ec) previously and it works but with different configuration it shows this error. I want to configure OpenPBS on node(client) and looks like i have to user this command so i tried it. Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try it without "--enable-alps" in the config file. enable-alps has nothing to do with commands.